# How to design Python scripts for sensitivity analysis of portfolios?

Tags: python, architecture, config, portfolio

My team is building a Python tool for portfolio analysis, and we need to add some sensitivity analysis (SA). Broadly speaking, we deal with two types of SA. One is multiple definitions of positions (e.g., certain asset classes are either included or excluded in the position), and the other is different assumptions for certain asset classes (e.g., take a percentage haircut off).

Our tool is a group of scripts containing functions (not OOP), and we use "import" to link all the scripts together.

One quick solution is to add arguments for the functions. The challenges are there are too many arguments shared by several scripts. Then, the scripts are written by different team members, hence it is hard to coordinate, especially if we will make more changes in the future.

Another idea is to have a config file that contains the True/False values for inclusion/exclusion and some hard-coded values. Then the config file can be imported and all the values become global variables, and each of the programmers writes their scripts based on the config file.

I don't have experience in OOP, so would try to avoid switching the paradigm of our tool.